# SSH stops working

Tags: ssh, vps

I'm using Oracle cloud VPS service and  I have one (for me) weird problem with VPS. I made an instance of ubuntu, I made a new user with a password and everything worked fine. After some time (maybe 1-2 hours) SSH just stops working. Then I reboot instance of VM, and again everything works fine for 1-2 hours and than again SSH stops working. In dashboard instance is runinning normally, everything seems fine, but I can't connect.

ssh -vvv username@ip gives this:

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.1.1o 3 May 2022

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *

debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 130.61.xxx.xxx is address

debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts'

debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2'

debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering

debug1: Connecting to 130.61.xxx.xxx [130.61.xxx.xxx] port 22.

debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
```

Comment: Stay connected for more than 2 hours and look at system utilization and other errors on system log. Do you have something running that uses too much CPU, like crypto mining?

Comment: I don't have anything on it. It is clean install of ubuntu. I only made update & upgrade

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421324/edit) your question and add some more details like the version of Ubuntu that you are running on your server, or what version of the Openssh-server you are running on it.  I have a sneaking suspicion that it might be a memory leak if it is killing out the ssh daemon after that amount of time.